# Italics/roman in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I use a BibTeX style which automatically italicises booktitles (using `\emph`). I have certain entries which contain italicised words in the title. I would like these to appear non-italicised (in roman) in the final PDF output. Using any of `\emph` or `\textit` or `\textrm` on these items doesn't seem to make any difference -- the whole title still appears in italics.

Minimal .bib entry

```
@PHDTHESIS{klein1974,
author = {Klein, Jared S.},
title = {The Particle \emph{u} in the {R}igveda},
school = {Yale},
year = {1974},
address = {New Haven, CT},
timestamp = {2009.12.04}
}
```

Minimal .bbl entry generated by `sp.bst`:

```
\bibitem[{Klein(1974)}]{klein1974}
Klein, Jared~S. 1974.
\newblock \emph{The particle \emph{u} in the {R}igveda}.
\newblock New Haven, CT: Yale dissertation.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\emph` should work because second-level emphasis is set in upright shape by default. If that doesn't work, try `\textup` instead.

Explanation: `\textrm` selects the serif family, `\textup` the upright shape. The five text font attributes encoding, family, series, shape, and size are all orthogonal to each other, and changing one attribute does not touch the others. This means that selecting the serif family via `\textrm` does not change the shape from italic to upright.

Comment: Although this points to some underlying problem with the `.bst` file, since having `\textup` in your `.bib` file isn't ideal given that it specifies the formatting rather than the semantics. So if another bibstyle requires upright titles, the bib records with `\textup` will have to be manually changed again so that the relevant words appear correctly with italics.

Comment: It's the "Semantics & Pragmatics" `sp.bst` (v. 2.1).

Comment: @Alan, BeSlayed: this is weird since `sp.bst` always uses `\emph` as you said, so an inner `\emph` should work just fine. I've tested the style now, and it works as expected, so something else must be wrong. Please post a minimal example.

Comment: @BeSlayed I can confirm too, that `\emph` works as expected with the `sp.bst`.  So to fix the problem properly, you really need to show us an example.

Comment: Added example above.

Comment: The .bbl file is fine, too—I think the problem is caused by something in your document.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be caused by the use of the `ulem` package. Fixed now. Many thanks!

Comment: @Philipp since this answer has gotten plenty of votes and been accepted, it might be helpful to expand your answer explain that it's really not an ideal solution and that some other source is likely the cause of the problem (as it was for BeSlayed.)