# biblatex - how to romanize words in italic title and v.v

Tags: biblatex, formatting

In this article:
[Italics/roman in BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17285/italics-roman-in-bibtex)
a question was raised but not really answered.   I have the same problem, but now with biblatex.   If my entry is e.g.:

```
 @article{Diensberg:boy,
    author= "Diensberg, Bernhard",
    title=  "The etymology of modern English \textit{boy}: a new hypothesis",
    journal="Medium {\AE}vum",
    volume= "50",
    number= "4",
    pages=  "79--87",
    year=   "1981",
  }
```

then I want "boy" to be romanized if the bibstyle in effect italicizes titles, and italicized if the current bibstyle romanizes titles.   I can't see anything in the biblatex manual to achieve this.  Is it possible?

I am doing this (and no more):

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,hyperref,dashed=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} % no "p" in postnotes
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{`#1'} % no quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{`#1'} % no quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{`#1'} % no quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat[mastersthesis]{title}{`#1'} % no quotes
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % no "In: "
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space} % comma after author, no t"."
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} % commas everywhere
```

Comment: Don't use the syntactic `\textit`. Use the semantic `\emph`.

Comment: That gives me "BOY" in a roman title.   I want italics in this case.

Comment: Please provide a full MWE.

Comment: Technically `\emph` should do exactly what you want. If it does not, we need to see what bibstyle you use and what modifications you have applied to it.

Comment: Even with that code `\emph` works like a charm and produces an italicised "boy". Just a note, you can use `csquotes` and `biblatex`'s `\mkbibquote` instead of `'#1'`: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}` (You might have to convince `csquotes` too use the right quotation marks though)

Comment: What do you mean by a “roman title”?

Comment: A non-italic title.